How do I import real life footages into Blender 2D so that I can draw over the footage?
I am currently preparing to work on an animation project that involves real life footages that I will have draw over to create effects such as fire, smoke, etc. The goal of this project for me to draw on top of the video reference in a style that is similar to Who frame Roger Rabbit for example.
I decided to draw a really rough animation of a fire with the intention of trying out Blender's effects when I decided that I should also test out the video import option.Immediately, I noticed that I am having issues with my video references becoming blurry and the frame rate dropping whenever I import them into my 2D workspace.
More specifically, in the video reference that I imported into Blender (which I shot using an IPhone), the swinging motion and the ball being hit seems to be extra blurry in comparison to my original footage prior to it being imported into the program. The fire animation that I drew on top of the footage (along with the added glow effects) does not seem to be affected with blurry frame of the video.
As for my process, I had created the fire animation along with the glow effects prior to importing the video. To import the video reference, I used the import option and the "images as planes" while setting the material type to Emit and the strength level to 1. The reason I chose to do this was so that I could draw on top of the video while having my drawings be clearly visible.
I would greatly appreciate any explanation and solutions to this issue. Thank you so much and have a wonderful day :)
*also, the image attached is my current settings for importing video references as planes. I believe it could be helpful in assisting my video imports are not matching the quality of the original videos.

Hello and welcome. Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead, see How to take a screenshot. Photos are harder to read because we have to look past external interferences (like reflections, smudges or Moiré patterns) and guess if we are looking at hardware issues such as a malfunctioning display or connections, a software level issue like driver malfunction or glitch, or actual artifacts or issues with the model itself.

It's difficult to understand what's behind your "Blurry" definition without a screenshot showing the problem. During import there's no quality loss, unless you explicitly change some import options, so my guess is that it's something about Motion Blur, that gets more noticeable when viewing frame to frame or at low speed.
About the frame rate dropping, probably it's because you're trying to view it in a realtime render shading mode, while it's better to stay in Solid shading, and activate its options "Flat" lighting and "Texture" Color.

Another method is to load the movie directly on the camera properties, as Background image, so to have easy control on Opacity, location, rot and scale, in relation with both the camera and the Grease Pencil object. Here you can also create a Low resolution proxy for the video if the frame rate dropping is an issue even in solid shading mode.


Hello! I have implemented your answer and it has helped me a great ton, as the quality and frame rate of my video references seem to now stabilize when I am editing in blender. If possible, could you examine my import settings? I have attached the imagine to my original post and would like to know if any of my settings could cause a potential issue moving forward.

All import settings are ok.
